# how to give different row id to sub group in in a group in sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

i have bunch of discount scheme for my item table , and for each item i have different discount scheme. now i want to give row id to that item but it should be start from zer0(0) for each item group, and when it got different DiscountId then it should be change, my table is in below image..[image]

now for an example, for ItemCode 429 there are 7 same discount with DiscountId 427 so for this all i want row Id 0(zero) but when change DiscountId, it means for Same ItemCode and 428 DiscountId,  then i want another RowId with increment. and when ItemCode change then rowId should be start from Zero(0).

can anyone help me please??

my current query is simpaly "select * from ItemDiscount_md".

Comment: Have a look at using [ROW_NUMBER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

**Test data:**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ITEMCode INT,DiscountId INT)
INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
(73,419),(73,419),(73,420),(73,420),(73,420),
(429,427),(429,427),(429,427),(429,427),(429,427),
(429,427),(429,427),(429,427),(429,428),(429,428)
```

**Query:**

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY tbl.ITEMCode 
                          ORDER BY DiscountId) AS Rownbr,
        tbl.*
    FROM
        @tbl AS tbl
)
SELECT
    CTE.Rownbr-1 AS RowNbr,
    CTE.DiscountId,
    CTE.ITEMCode
FROM
    CTE
```

Of course you can simplify the query by writing this:

```
SELECT
    (DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY tbl.ITEMCode 
                       ORDER BY DiscountId))-1 AS Rownbr,
    tbl.*
FROM
    @tbl AS tbl
```

I just thought it was nicer and more readable with a CTE function

**References:**

- [DENSE_RANK](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx)
- [OVER Clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)
- [Using Common Table Expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- [ROW_NUMBER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

**EDIT**

To answer the comment. No ROW_NUMBER will not return the same counter. This is the output with `DENSE_RANK`:

```
0   419 73
0   419 73
1   420 73
1   420 73
1   420 73
0   427 429
0   427 429
0   427 429
0   427 429
0   427 429
0   427 429
0   427 429
0   427 429
1   428 429
1   428 429
```

And this is with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
0   419 73
1   419 73
2   420 73
3   420 73
4   420 73
0   427 429
1   427 429
2   427 429
3   427 429
4   427 429
5   427 429
6   427 429
7   427 429
8   428 429
9   428 429
```

As you see `ROW_NUMBER`() recounts the group when the `DENSE_RANK` ranks the group

Comment: In this case, is ROW_NUMBER() will do the same ?

Comment: Thank you very very much for your answer, its really work for me and its exactly what i want, thank you so much..

Comment: yes , Row number is not return same counter for group.. its give different Id for all item(s)

Answer (score 2):

Just more simplified Arion's Answer

```
 DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ITEMCode INT,DiscountId INT)
INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
(73,419),
(73,419),
(73,420),
(73,420),
(73,420),
(429,427),
(429,427),
(429,427),
(429,427),
(429,427),
(429,427),
(429,427),
(429,427),
(429,428),
(429,428)

;
SELECT
    (DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ITEMCode ORDER BY DiscountId) -1) AS Rownbr,
    DiscountId,
    ITEMCode
FROM
    @tbl
```

Comment: hi , thank you so much for your reply.. yes its simple then above query , both the query works for me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

if you got data like this: (from the image) @temp table

```
itemcode    DiscountId  DayId
----------- ----------- -----------
102         416         2
102         416         3
102         416         4
79          419         3
79          419         1
79          420         2
79          420         1
```

use row_number() to get below result

```
itemcode    DiscountId  DayId       rowid
----------- ----------- ----------- --------------------
102         416         2           1
102         416         3           2
102         416         4           3
79          419         3           1
79          419         1           2
79          420         2           1
79          420         1           2
```

SQL example:

```
select itemcode, DiscountId, DayId
, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Discountid order by discountid) as 'rowid'
from @temp
```

Comment: Don't forget the `-1` asked on rownumber ! :)